# Why does this recursive function for square-roots give the wrong result?

Tags: haskell, square-root

I made this tail-recursive function for computing square roots:

`sqrt x n a = if n == 0 then a else sqrt x (n - 1) (a + x/a)/2`

For some reason, it gives the wrong result when n is greater than 1, meaning when it's asked to improve the approximation, a, more than once. It returns a number that's closer and closer to 0 as n grows. I tried implementing the same recursive formula in different ways like this:

`sqrt x n = if n == 0 then 1 else (a + x/a)/2 where a = sqrt x (n - 1)`

`sqrt x = 1:map (\a -> (a + x/a)/2) (sqrt x)`

And that all works fine. It's only the first example that doesn't work and I can't figure out why, as much as I try.

Comment: The division is applied to the result of `sqrt`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression:

```
sqrt x n a = if n == 0 then a else  sqrt x (n - 1) (a + x/a)  / 2
```

is parsed as:

```
sqrt x n a = if n == 0 then a else (sqrt x (n - 1) (a + x/a)) / 2
```

So the `sqrt x (n-1) (a+x/a)` is seen as the numerator of a division by two. You should add brackets here:

```
sqrt x n a = if n == 0 then a else sqrt x (n - 1) ((a + x/a) / 2)
```

With the given, fix, we can for example calculate the square root of five as:

```
Prelude> sqrt 5 10 1
2.23606797749979
```

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_5), it is:

```
2.23606797749978969640917366873127623544061835961152572427089…
```

so this is already quite close.